# To check if you have replied to client email via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written VBA code to check if my team has responded to email.

```vb
Dim O As Outlook.Application
Dim R As Long

Sub project2()
Set O = New Outlook.Application
Dim Omail As Outlook.MailItem
Set Omail = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS = O.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim FOL As Outlook.Folder
Set FOL = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("MD-GPS")
R = 2
For Each Omail In FOL.Items
    Cells(R, 1) = Omail.Subject
    Cells(R, 2) = Omail.SenderEmailAddress
            
    Call REPLY_STATUS(Omail.Subject, Omail.SenderEmailAddress)
            
    R = R + 1
    On Error Resume Next
Next Omail
End Sub


Sub REPLY_STATUS(MailSubject As String, MailSender As String)

Dim SentEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set SentEmail = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim ONS2 As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS2 = O.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        
Dim FOL2 As Outlook.Folder
Set FOL2 = ONS2.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Dim check As String
check = "RE: " & MailSubject

For Each SentEmail In FOL2.Items
    If check = SentEmail.Subject And MailSender = SentEmail.Recipients(1).Address Then
        Cells(R, 3) = "Yes"
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
Next SentEmail

End Sub
```

The code runs but

1. In most cases it captures something other than the sender's email address in an Excel sheet.
   [image]
2. As we daily receive 500+ emails, the code becomes too slow as it checks the entire folder from the scratch. Is there a possibility I can add a start date that I can mention in the Excel sheet and the code will start from that date.
3. It is also not filling column 3 i.e. if replied however my team has actually replied to those emails.
4. It is not picking up the latest emails from the defined sub-folder ("MD-GPS"), why is that happening?

Note: To handle STMP exchange account error, I tried using the following `MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` but if I change the sub-folder to something else, it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you do not need to create `SentEmail` - get rid of the

```
Set SentEmail = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

line.

Secondly, never loop through all items in a folder - use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.

Thirdly, you are seeing an EX type address (as opposed to SMTP). Check `MailItem.Sender.Type` property - if it is "SMTP", use `MailItem.Sender.Address`. Otherwise (in case of "EX") use `MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`.

That being said, you can check if anybody replied to the original message at all - check if `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003`) is present - 103 is `EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOALLand` 102 is `EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOSENDER`. If the property is not set at all, there is no reason to search.

To search for a matching subject, use a query like

```
"[Subject] = ' & MailSubject  & "'"
```

Note that Outlook Object Model will not let you search on the message recipients or attachments. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use something like the following. You can specify Recipients as one of the search fields, and Redemption will create a restriction on recipient name / address / SMTP address

```
set session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
session.MAPIOBJECT = O.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set SentEmail = FOL2.Items.Find("""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" = '" & MailSubject & "' AND Recipients = '" & MailSender & "'")
```

Note that most MAPI stores won't search on `PR_SUBJECT`, only on `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT` (which is the subject without the RE: or FW: prefix) - which is what the snippet above is using.

Comment: is it possible to add start date so that the code should search the email starting from the given start date ?

Comment: Of course - you can add a restriction on the `ReceivedTime` property to be greater than or less than any value.

Comment: rest all sorted, can you please help me with received time in the code, where do I need to mention it ?

Comment: Set FOL = msgs.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(CDate(msg.ReceivedTime), "01/10/2021 00:00") & "'")     i tried the above but didnt work

Comment: sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '02/09/2021'"

R = 2
For Each Omail In FOL.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
  finally, this worked but I think something is still weird in the code , the first email its retrieving is asof 5th Feb 2021

Comment: That query looks fine to me.

Comment: I have added two more attachments in my original post, 1) the latest email it picks in the excel sheet
2) the received time of the email both are not matching, I don't see it right

Comment: the issue got resolved, it was stemming from the wrong date format.