# VBA Script - Verify answered

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a problem about a macro in VBA which, I want to use in outlook.

I have a function mailbox, and i want to verify, did i respond to the sender in the 7 days.

I made a macro, but it doesn't work. It just doesn't work on a larger scale, and i do not have any idea why.

I expect the macro to work.

```
Sub CheckResponses()
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim folder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim message As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim respondedOnTime As Integer
    Dim noResponse As Integer
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim titlesNoResponse As String
    
    respondedOnTime = 0
    noResponse = 0
    titlesNoResponse = ""
    
    startDate = DateSerial(2023, 1, 1)
    endDate = DateSerial(2024, 1, 1)
    
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = ns.Folders("test@work.pl").Folders("Inbox")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each message In folder.Items
        If message.Class = olMail And message.SentOn >= startDate And message.SentOn <= endDate Then
            If message.ReceivedTime <= message.SentOn + 7 Then
                
                If message.ReplyRecipients.Count > 0 Then
                    If message.ReplyRecipients(1).Address = message.SenderEmailAddress Then
                        respondedOnTime = respondedOnTime + 1
                    Else
                        noResponse = noResponse + 1
                        titlesNoResponse = titlesNoResponse & message.Subject & vbCrLf
                    End If
                Else
                    noResponse = noResponse + 1
                    titlesNoResponse = titlesNoResponse & message.Subject & vbCrLf
                End If
            Else
                noResponse = noResponse + 1
                titlesNoResponse = titlesNoResponse & message.Subject & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next

    On Error GoTo 0
    
    MsgBox "Responded on time to " & respondedOnTime & " messages." & vbCrLf & _
           "No response: " & noResponse & vbCrLf & _
           "Titles of messages without response:" & vbCrLf & titlesNoResponse, vbInformation, "Response Report"
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare message as Object then you can delete `On Error Resume Next`. Even if this has no impact leave `On Error Resume Next` deleted.

Comment: `If message.Class = olMail And message.SentOn >= startDate And message.SentOn <= endDate Then`  When assessing a list of True/False tests combined using And/Or, VBA assesses *all tests* before applying the And/Or to get the final result - ie. it does not "short-circuit". In your code above if the first test `message.Class = olMail` returns False the other tests are still run, potentially causing a run-time error.  You need to use multiple `If Then` to prevent that.

Comment: I suggest it may not be useful to fix this code. You could try adjusting code from [To check if you have replied to client email via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69415294/to-check-if-you-have-replied-to-client-email-via-vba) that compares received mail to sent mail.